# Problem with testfor command: "expected '{' as first char"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an adventure map but I have a problem.

For the testfor command I put `/testfor @p [r=3]` but it doesn't work.

The command block says:

```
[13:13:15] Data tag parsing failed: Invalid tag encountered, expected '{' as first char.
```

I am using Minecraft version 1.8.8.

Comment: General advice for map-making: `testfor` is a *very* limited command, and in ~90% of all cases using (the newer) `execute` is better. That is, most cases where the `testfor` triggers another command if the result is true. The rule of thumb would be to use `execute` unless you **know exactly** that it won't do for your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the space between `@p` and `[r=3]`.

Try the following command:

`/testfor @p[r=3]`

Comment: @sabsub If it works for you, you can put the answer as accepted (click the little check mark under the votes)

Answer (score -1):

The Syntax is just a little bit wrong here's yours:

```
/testfor @p [r=3]
```

The Correct One:

```
/testfor @p[r=3]
```

Side Note: If your using `/testfor @p[x=1,y=1,z=1,r=1]` with negative numbers, it won't work.

Comment: This adds nothing not already said, I'm afraid.  Do you have anything extra to add?

Comment: Why yes, I just did.