# Teleport Player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a maze, and at certain parts the players need to be teleported.
This is my command so far:

`/tp @a [x=-1034, y=34, z=-302 r=2] ~ ~ ~30`

So this says, if a player is within 2 blocks of these coordinates then teleport the player 30 blocks south (positive z).

I can't have the command blocks at `x=-1034`, `y=34` and `z=-302`, which is why that part of the command is necessary.

Can someone tell me if this command exists please!

Comment: Please do some research before posting a question.  This problem has [come](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/241496/1351) [up](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/229942/1351) [before](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/240908/1351), and the fact that it's so basic means you're not trying hard enough to solve your own problem first.

Comment: ***If the command exists?*** So try it yourself?...

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it isn't working is because there is a space between the `@a` and the square brackets.

This command should work.

```
/tp @a[x=-1034,y=34,z=-302,r=2] ~ ~ ~30
```

Comment: If this helped, please click the tick next to the votes. Thanks!

Comment: That command won't work.  You still have spaces, and you're missing a comma.

Comment: @MBraedley How stupid of me, I automatically fixed the space and forgot to check the rest :) fixed